# Creating a hardware independant image possible?

Tags: centos, images

I swapped from Windows Community to Linux Community and am struggling a bit with images.

You can on Windows install a system, then strip it from all saved hardware details and create an image.
This way is it neutral to almost any hardware it will face. Only exception will be the hardware abstraction layer for CPU architecture.

Now on CentOS my images may already fail just due to a different BIOS version when I use Clonezilla.

Are there comparable tools in Linux world?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a portable Linux system, there are

- **[Persistent] live systems.** This kind of system is very portable between computers with different hardware. It is easy to make it boot both in UEFI and BIOS mode.
- **Installed systems,** where you avoid proprietary drivers (rely only on the built-in linux hardware drivers). This kind of system is also portable between computers with different hardware, much more so than what you would expect, when you are used to Windows.

---

Both kinds of systems may fail with hardware, that only works with proprietary drivers, for example new high-end nvidia graphic chips or broadcom wifi chips, where you have to install a relevant driver for things to work properly.

Comment: @JanS, Please let me know if you want more details about (for example) persistent live systems or about linux distros where it is relatively easy to create portable systems and how to do it.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't in the office yesterday.
It is an installed system i am am looking for.
The hardware uses drivers shipped with the iso. so no surprises from that side

Comment: @JanS, When you use built-in linux drivers, and they work in all the target computers, fine                              :-) As you indicate in the question, there could still be a problem related to the boot mode. Normally an installed system will be installed either in UEFI mode or BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode). But if necessary, it is possible to make an installed 64-bit linux system boot both in UEFI and BIOS mode. See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS).

Comment: @JanS, Another tip is to create an OEM system, which gives you an opportunity to clone systems and as a final installation step make the system unique (system ID and user ID). See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview). I think there might be corresponding tools/methods for several linux distros.

Comment: Cheers mate :) I will look into it

Answer (score 1):

> ...Windows ... neutral to almost any hardware

Windows will care about archetecture changes, missing drivers, etc.

Linux being more customizable and way faster is more flexible so many just use a custom installer. CentOS 7 is old(2014), but has tools like composer
https://docs.centos.org/en-US/centos/install-guide/Composer/

Comment: Composer is indeed an interesting tool. Not applicable for my current topic tbh but interesting for upcoming tasks. Cheers :)